# It should request a password even when I'm in the administrator user

Tags: administrator, windows-10-pro

[image]

> Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?

I want that every time this message shows up, one of the administrators' passwords would be needed, even when I'm in an administrator user account.

I already tried to play around with settings in local group policy, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: For clarification, are you using the default `Administrator` account or a user that's a part of the `Administrators` group?

Comment: A user that's a part of the Administrators

Comment: [Require password for elevated prompts even when you are an administrator in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1763683/241386)