# Require password for elevated prompts even when you are an administrator in Windows

Tags: windows, passwords, administrator

How do I require a password for administrator actions (when the elevation prompt appears) when I'm an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Edit group policy", open the Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" and select "Prompt for credentials" (or "Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop").

More info in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj852205(v=ws.11))